# How to filter mongo db documents using timespan with respect to Epoch time?

Tags: mongodb

I have a document format as follows in MongoDB. The UpdatedOn is Epoch time. Is there a way I can filter the documents in my collection so that I get only the docs updated within the past hour?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c29f3123d8cf714fd9cdb87"),
    "Machine" : "machine1",
    "Pools" : [
        "Pool1",
        "Pool2"
    ],
    "UpdatedOn": 1546330204
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the Epoch time on a client side, try in JS / Mongo shell:

```
db.col.find({ UpdatedOn: { $gt: new Date().valueOf() - 1000 * 60 * 60 } })
```

[valueOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_valueof_date.asp) returns the number of millisecond since midnight January 1, 1970 UTC